# List "order by" malfunction

Tags: .net, string

I have a class like one in which student sit.
i have location like B6 B7 B8 B9 B10 B11
I get it in this order if i use FindAll with in some class(one oops version)
everything goes fine untill i do

```
    someclass.OrderBy(r => r.location);
```

and after that location becomes B10 B11 B6 B7 B8 B9
what is going wrong here. I am better without using orderBY then but can any one tell me reason for problem I am having ?

Comment: It orders by alpha-numeric order, so 10 is before 6 because 1 is before 6.

Comment: In the string order : B10 < B11 < B6 < B7 < B8 < B9

Comment: Try changing B6, B7 to B06,B07

Comment: @DorCohen That's a clever solution! (if it is possible)

Comment: Probably the appropriate approach here (assuming you wrote whatever class `r` belongs to, is to have it implement `IComparable`, define an appropriate comparison method (involving `location`) and use `someclass.OrderBy(r => r);` As Dor Cohen suggests, using a fixed number of digits would also be a good approach if that's a possibility.

Comment: unluckily B06, B07 is not possible, wow i never thought this could be problem thanks everyone  yes location is a list of string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could implement your own custom comparer ...

```
class CustomCompare : IComparer<string>
{
    private static readonly char[] _digits = "0123456789".ToArray();

    public int Compare(string a, string b)
    {
        //assuming alpha start, numeric end
        var alphaA = a.TrimEnd(_digits);
        var alphaB = b.TrimEnd(_digits);
        var alphaCompareTo = alphaA.CompareTo(alphaB);

        if (alphaCompareTo != 0)
        {
            return alphaCompareTo;
        }

        var numericA = int.Parse(a.Substring(alphaA.Length));
        var numericB = int.Parse(b.Substring(alphaB.Length));

        return numericA.CompareTo(numericB);
    }
}
```

... and use it like so ...

```
someclass.OrderBy(r => r.location, new CustomCompare());
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because the strings are being compared as... well, strings.  `'1'` is less than `'6'`, so the lexical comparison will stop at that character.

It sounds like you want a [natural sort](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting) instead of a lexical sort.

Comment: Agreed. This complements my answer

Answer (score 3):

I suppose your `location` property (or field) is a string?

You could **either** write a `Comparer<>` like:

```
sealed class LocationComparer : Comparer<string>
{
  // expect strings like "B3" or "C26"
  public override int Compare(string x, string y)
  {
    int result = x[0].CompareTo(y[0]);
    if (result != 0)
      return result;
    result = ushort.Parse(x.Substring(1)).CompareTo(ushort.Parse(y.Substring(1)));
    return result;
  }
}
```

Use it like `sorted = someclass.OrderBy(r => r.location, new LocationComparer());`.

**Or** you can change the type of your `location` to a class in the style of:

```
// this class inherits the IComparable implementation of Tuple`2
sealed class Location : Tuple<char, ushort>
{
  public Location(char letter, ushort number)
    : base(char.ToUpper(letter), number)
  {
  }

  public Location(string locationString)
    : this(letter: locationString[0], number: ushort.Parse(locationString.Substring(1)))
  {
  }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return Item1.ToString() + Item2.ToString();
  }
}
```

Inside the `Someclass` class the `location` has type `Location`. Then your original `sorted = someclass.OrderBy(r => r.location);` will work.

Both solutions are just sketches. I guess you would want to add some sanity checks.

Answer (score 2):

Order by uses string ordering, not numeric ordering.

```
'B10' < 'B6'
```

Each entry is compared, character by character:

```
'B10'
'B6'
  ^
```

This is the character that matters (as B is the same).  '6' > '1'.

Answer (score 1):

the orderby is working correctly, please observe that the string B10 comes before the string B11, which in turns comes before B6

please note that you are trying to order a `List<string>` (or that's what i think) and not a `List<int>`

Answer (score 1):

In order to render numbers in strings lexicographically sortable, they'd need to be padded i.e. B01 < B06 < B10 as B6 is > B10 as it's done left to right. So your simple option is to pad if you know your upper bounds, otherwise you'll have to rethink a little.

Answer (score 0):

Are they always going to be in the form "X###"? If so you can use:

```
yourListObject.OrderBy(r => int.Parse(r.location.SubString(1)));
```

That's one workaround. If the situation is much more complex, then you'll need to create a comparer object for also a newly created Location class.

Answer (score 0):

You need a natural sort algorithm. Take [this one from Ian](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting) and call it:

```
someclass.OrderBy(r => r.location, new EnumerableComparer<String>());
```